# How can I join two lines together from two separate files in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

For example in File1.txt I have a list of strings like so:

`Red|
Orange|
Yellow|
Green|
Blue|`

And in File2.txt I have a list of strings like so:

`Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday`

I would like to produce a File3.txt with this effect.

`Red|Monday
Orange|Tuesday
Yellow|Wednesday
Green|Thursday
Blue|Friday`

Currently I am using Notepad++ v7.2.2 (32-Bit).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution albeit a kind of a roundabout way of doing it.

First I took my data from File1 and put it into an excel spreadsheet and organized it so one line uses one row.

Then I did the same thing for the data from File2 ,but put it into the second column.

I then Selected my two rows of data, copied them, and pasted them to File3.

For my specific case I had to do a regex find and replace `/t` to remove extra tab spaces that were added.

I still would like to know if notepad++ has the capability to do what I want thought. Instead of having to use a silly excel sheet.